# WSUS Upstream and Downstream in different domains

Tags: windows-update

I've spent quite some time googling but with little success.

I have 1 WSUS upstream server and multiple downstream servers. Someone before me set this up. Main thing is - upstream server belongs to DOMAIN1, while all downstream servers belong to DOMAIN2. All downstream servers are configured to be Autonomous (by design).

Everything work just fine, I can use downstream server to see updates, approve them and they get downloaded from the upstream server.
However:

1. Any reports I run on the upstream server fail to include all of the computers from the downstream servers.
2. I can't add any of the downstream servers to the upstream server wsus management console, just get an error that it fails to connect. Checked the firewall, comms allowed.

I suspect this might have something to do with the fact that my servers belong to different domains? Maybe something g about authentication or smth like this?